# How to hide other results and just show first result in ListView after Scanned QR Code

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm developing Scan Update App that scan QR Code and update it to Database.

Here is my code for Update to Database.

```
private void updateDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    int OKcnt = 0;
    int NotOKcnt = 0;
    String shows = "";
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                sp.getString("URL","jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test"),
                sp.getString("User","Test"), sp.getString("Pass","Test")
        );
        for (String scanned : scannedList) {
            String[] splits = scanned.split(",");
            String show = "Show Table";
            String table = "BedRegistration";
            String set = "DocStatus";
            String set2 = "IP";
            String where = "Name";
            String where2 = scanned;
            
            show = splits[0].equals("") ? table :splits [0];
            table = splits[1].equals("") ? table : splits[1];
            where = splits[2].equals("") ? where : splits[2];
            where2 = splits[3].equals("") ? where2 : splits[3];

            show = show + ". ";
            shows = shows + show ;

            String SQL = "UPDATE " + table + " SET ";
            String SQLWhere = " WHERE " + where + "='" + where2 + "'";
            for (int i = 4; i < splits.length; i=i+2) {
                set = splits[i].equals("") ? set : splits[i];
                set2 = splits[i+1].equals("") ? set2 : splits[i+1];
                SQL += set + " = '" + set2 + "', ";
            }
            SQL = SQL.substring(0, SQL.length() - 2);
            SQL = SQL + SQLWhere;
            Statement pstmt = conn.createStatement();

            try {
                int i = pstmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
                System.out.println(SQL+"DB result = "+i);
                OKcnt++;
            } catch (SQLException e){
                NotOKcnt++;
                continue;
            }
       }
```

And here is my Scan QR Code code.

```
public void scanBar(View v) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
        intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        showDialog(this, "No BarScanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
    }
}
```

How can I hide other results and just show first result which is String Show?

I have tried to make two listviews, one listview to store all the data and hide it and another listview to store and show just first result, but it didn't work.

Here is my listview and adapter code.

```
public static final String DB_CONNECTOR = "DB_Connector" ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(org.starprise.mobile.R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(org.starprise.mobile.R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    // Enable the Up button
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // We get the ListView component from the layout
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, scannedList);
    lv.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Here is Button that i clicked to Update Database.

```
public void updateDB(View v) {
    asyncDBHandling as = new asyncDBHandling(this);
    as.execute(sp,scannedList);
    //new asyncDBHandling().execute(sp,scannedList);
}
```

Here is Code to process after Scan QR Code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            scannedList.add(contents);
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: show your data rendering code

Comment: i mean listview and adapters code

Comment: I've edited my post @HarKal

Comment: just one more thing can you please log the results once what data you get

Comment: in your code you areb getting a single string

Comment: The result at ListView is like this = Order No 1, c_order, c_order_id, 12345, Description, It Worked. I want just show "Order No 1", i wanna hide the other results. @HarKal

Comment: r you sure it is going to be the same for ever. if i write in general terms then the format is => string, string, string, int, string, string ?

Comment: the format is always constant

Comment: look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the format of your results is always constant then you can rely on this code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            String first_result = contents.substring( 0, contents.indexOf(","));

            scannedList.add(first_result);
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }
}
```

leme know if some problem occurrs

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't show in the ListView, just blank

Comment: just try logging the data with Log.i("whole data : ", contents); and Log.i("first data : ", first_result); in onActivityResults and show me the values please

Comment: Okay i'll try it later, i got another job to do for a while

Comment: It worked! But how to keep the other data to Update it to Database but it doesn't show in ListView?

Comment: then just store String contents to your database and while showing in listview use the technique i mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

In your ListView Adapter, you will probably have a List, ArrayList or any object that grows in size from which your ListView renders it's data.

What determines how many of the data in the ArrayList or List to render is the return value of the `getCount()` method.

Do something of the sort

```
package com.fz5.emminent17.adapters;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * Created by Francis Ilechukwu 20/11/2017.
 */

public class SearchResult Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean showOnlyFirst = false;

    public FacultyAdapter(String[] searchResults) {
        Collections.addAll(this.searchResults, searchResults);
    }

    public void setShouldShowFirstOnly(boolean showOnlyFirst) {
        this.showOnlyFirst = showOnlyFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (showOnlyFirst) {
            return 1;
        }
        return searchResults.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return searchResults.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // Your Normal getView implementation
    }
}
```

Notice the `showOnlyFirst` boolean, it's a control variable to use on case you want to show all results later or by the press of a button.

However, to show only first, set it to `true`.